# Error maquetando con flexbox

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

Éste es mi código:

```css
.filadisco1 {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.discox {
  width: 250px;
  height: 420px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;   
  flex-direction: column;     
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;  
  margin-top: 34px;
  /* margin-left: 50px;*/
  background-color: #212f31;
}
```

```html
<div class="filadisco1"> 

  <div class="discox">
    <a class="ablanco" href="la-desvirtualizacion-de-las-ideas/">
      <img class="imgdiscosx" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/jamondisco5.jpg">
    </a>
    <p class="parrafodisco">La Desvirtualización de las ideas (2015)</p>
    <p class="parrafodescrip"> La idea sigue siendo la misma. Rock cannábico y kalimochero. La grabación [...]</p>    
  </div>

  <div class="discox">
    <a class="ablanco" href="bokerones-muertos/">
      <img class="imgdiscosx" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/jamondisco4.png">
    </a>
    <p class="parrafodisco">Bokerones muertos (2014)</p>
    <p class="parrafodescrip"> Este nuevo disco, musicalmente más tranquilo, es el tercero que hacemos juntos.[...]</p>    
  </div>

  <div class="discox">
    <a class="ablanco" href="la-democracia-ha-muerto-vol2/">
      <img class="imgdiscosx" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/jamondisco3.jpg">
    </a>
    <p class="parrafodisco">La democracia ha muerto vol 2 (2013)</p>
    <p class="parrafodescrip">Consta de siete temas de rock cannábico y kalimochero. Fernando de la Pola sigue [...]</p>    
  </div>

  <div class="discox">
    <a class="ablanco" href="la-democracia-ha-muerto-vol1/">
      <img class="imgdiscosx" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/jamondisco2.jpg">
    </a>
    <p class="parrafodisco">La democracia ha muerto vol 1 (2012)</p>
    <p class="parrafodescrip"> Ahora Fernando se junta con Dani, que ya había estado en Melilla en Jamón de Mono. Así surge [...]</p>    
  </div>

  <div class="discox">
    <a class="ablanco" href="se-busca-banda/">
      <img class="imgdiscosx" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/jamondisco1.jpg">
    </a>
    <p class="parrafodisco">Se busca banda (2010)</p>
    <p class="parrafodescrip"> Disco grabado durante el verano del 2009. Fernando decide proponerle el proyecto de producción de doce temas [...]</p>    
  </div>

</div>
```

Tengo el contenedor padre y dentro 5 hijos; como son 5 hijos, los 2 de abajo en un width de 960px se ven centrados pero no están alineados con los 3 elementos de arriba.

Con `justify-content:space-around;` hago que tengan la misma separación entre los elementos y estos con el contenedor padre, pero los 2 de abajo se centran y rompen la consistencia. Los 2 hijos de abajo tendrían que estar debajo de los 2 primeros elementos de arriba.

¿Por qué ocurre esto?¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es el comportamiento **natural** para los valores `center` y `space-around`. Lo que deseas actualmente no puede hacerse de forma normal con flexbox. Sin embargo, como en todo, se pueden pensar y crear hacks para simular este comportamiento.

Hace ya un tiempo buscaba lo mismo porque quería el mismo comportamiento para una galería de productos y encontré una solución interesante.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: .5rem;
}
.container .box {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 200px;
}
.container .box.green {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
.container .box.blue {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.container .box.gold {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.container .box.purple {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
}
.container .box.orange {
  background-color: #d35400;
}
.container .box.midnight {
  background-color: #34495e;
}
.container .box.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.container .box.silver {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}

.filling {
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="container">
    
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box gold"></div>
    <div class="box orange"></div>
    <div class="box midnight"></div>
    <div class="box purple"></div>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box silver"></div>
    <div class="filling"></div>
    <div class="filling"></div>
    <div class="filling"></div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

El ancho de los divs de *relleno* deben de:

- Tener el mismo ancho de los ítems
- Tener el mismo margen de los ítems
- No tener alto. Esto es importante.